# Creating a Barplot using pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt, bar-chart, pyqtgraph

I need plotting an animated bar chart with pyqtgraph. With animate i mean a chart, which updates his values given by a serial port. For now, a not-animated plot will be enough. I would like to implement a plot which looks something like this:

[image: horizontal barplot]

My input data is given in a dict which looks like this: (Key=Timestamp, Value=Event)

```
{1604496095: 0, 1604496096: 4, 1604496097: 6, 1604496098: 8, 1604496099: 9, 1604496100: 7, 1604496101: 8 ... }
```

Unfortunately I can't offer a lot of code as I have not been able to create a diagram similar to the one in the picture. So far I only have the corresponding window

Thats my window for now:

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore
import pyqtgraph as pg
import sys

class Plotter(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, *args)
        self.setWindowTitle("Test-Monitor")
        self.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(800, 400))
        self.setupUI()

    def setupUI(self):
        self.plot = pg.PlotWidget()
        self.plot.showGrid(x=True, y=True)
        self.plot.setLabel('left', 'Event')
        self.plot.setLabel('bottom', 'Time')

        self.setCentralWidget(self.plot)


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
plotter = Plotter()
plotter.show()
app.exec_()
```

I would appreciate a code example that uses pyqtgraph that comes close to the picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [BarGraphItem](https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/graphicsItems/bargraphitem.html), and add all "bars" using arrays of values (or add individual BarGraphItems, if you prefer):

```
    def buildData(self, data):
        stamps = sorted(data.keys())
        zero = min(stamps)
        x0 = []
        y0 = []
        width = []
        brushes = []
        for i, stamp in enumerate(stamps):
            try:
                nextStamp = stamps[i + 1]
            except:
                nextStamp = stamp + 1
            x0.append(stamp - zero)
            y0.append(data[stamp])
            width.append(nextStamp - stamp)
            brushes.append(QtGui.QColor(QtCore.Qt.GlobalColor(data[stamp])))

        barItem = pg.BarGraphItem(x0=x0, y0=y0, width=width, height=1, 
            brushes=brushes)
        self.plot.addItem(barItem)
```

Note that the brush colors are chosen using `Qt.GlobalColor` just for the purpose of this example, you should probably use a dictionary or a function that returns a color based on the value.

Comment: Works perfectly, Thanks. I have another question maybe you can help me. I want to make a list of checkboxes next to the plot which i want to connect to the bars inside the plot. Do i have to create a `pg.BarGraphItem` for every single value to show or hide them or is this possible with the given solution?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding. Do you want to be able to show/hide the bars individually? If that's the case, yes, you must create single items, and that's due to the way those items are painted (they are actually QPicture instances).

Comment: Yes that's exactly what i wanna do. Do you have a good approach for me how i create a bar for each individual task (Y)?

Comment: I believe you can create individual bars using the following arguments: `BarGraphItem(x0=[x], y0=y, width=width, height=1, brushes=[brush])`; note that in this case, the variables are individual values for each bar (not lists), but the x0 and brushes arguments must be arrays for that class, and that's why they're enclosed in square brackets.

Comment: @enyo note that if you don't need particular interaction, you can even use a simple QGraphicsRectItem.